# Dúvida quanto a estrutura de um caso de uso

Tags: uml, casos-de-uso

Tenho o seguinte caso de uso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho três dúvidas, são elas:

- Registrar-se é um nome adequado?
- No caso acima é correto ter o elemento CRUD?
- **Gerenciar usuário** deveria ser **Manter usuário**?
- Este include **Buscar** me parece dispensável, deveria remover?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sobre suas dúvidas vamos responde-las em partes.

**Registrar-se é um nome adequado?**

Na teoria geral da estrutura de caso de uso, utilizamos nomes com verbos para determinar que alguma tarefa será executa, isso não é uma regra, mas considera-se uma boa prática dentro da UML.

Vamos ao seguinte exemplo, temos um hipotético cenário.

Uma fábrica tem algumas peças de oficina para serem vendidas e precisa entregar para o cliente, dono de uma oficina. Se caso você coloca no seu diagrama apenas "peças" você não consegue entender do que se trata. Existe uma quantidade imensa de ações possíveis para fazer com peças, como por exemplo entregar peças, comprar peças, vender peças.

Como falado ali em cima, o ideal é colocar um verbo para indicar qual ação está acontecendo.

Então, registrar, registrar-se, cadastrar é um nome ideal

**No caso acima é correto ter o elemento CRUD?**

Não, não é correto ter o elemento CRUD, dentro do caso de uso, não representamos funcionalidades do sistema, de uma forma a nível de sistema. Para isso existe outros diagramas, como o de classes, no diagrama de casos de uso só representamos as ações que um ator vai fazer.

Como demonstrado no exemplo anterior, só devemos mostrar no diagrama de casos de uso as ações feita pelos atores, não as funcionalidades dessas ações.

**Gerenciar usuário deveria ser Manter usuário?**
Não entendi essa pergunta, tem que ver seu cenário

**Este include Buscar me parece dispensável, deveria remover?**
Para saber se devemos remover ou não, devemos mais uma vez entrar nas teorias de caso de uso.

**Include**

No diagrama de casos de uso, o elemento include é usado quando uma funcionalidade é totalmente dependente da outra, ou seja, é obrigatória.
Explicando de uma forma melhor, vamos a um exemplo.

Gerar Nota Fiscal seria um include de Realizar Venda.

A nota fiscal só pode ser emitida após realizar uma venda e de forma obrigatória, não pode ser opcional.

**Extends**

O extends, é usado quando existe também uma dependência, mas essa dependência não é obrigatória, a funcionalidade pode ocorrer independentemente da outra.

Explicando de uma forma melhor, vamos a um exemplo

Enviar nota fiscal por e-mail seria extends de realizar venda.

Pode ser enviada nota fiscal por e-mail, mas não de forma obrigatória.

**Respondendo sua pergunta**

Vai depender do seu cenário, do seu exercício, não da pra dizer com certeza se está errado ou não.

Comment: Para evitar o "-se" em Registrar-se, pode ser Registrar <ator>: Registrar usuário, Registrar cliente, por exemplo.

Comment: Sim @Piovezan, prefiro também utilizar dessa abordagem. Registrar Usuário.

Answer (score 2):

Resposta teórica.

Você não tem um caso de uso, mas vários.

Não há nada de errado com o nome Registrar-se.

Já Efetuar Login não é tipicamente retratada como um caso de uso, de acordo com a definição de um caso de uso (trazer um benefício concreto a um ator). Ela pode ser um passo de um caso de uso. Observação: alguns retratam sim como caso de uso o efetuar login.

Não faz sentido um caso de uso estender um CRUD, até porque eu pelo menos não vejo um CRUD como algo genérico que possa ser estendido.

(Essa é a parte que tenho menos certeza) Buscar também me parece fugir de algo que traz um benefício concreto, mas posso estar enganado. Em todo caso acredito que a ideia do include é incluir cenários que sejam comuns a vários casos de uso. Não vejo o Buscar fazendo muito sentido por si só.

Comment: Nem se coloca CRUD dentro de um caso de uso